# where can I look at the variation of the price of the stocks ? Are all of them easily availble?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Where can I look at the variation of the price of stocks please ?

I'm not investing but I'm curious to follow some variation of the price of the stock of some start-ups.

Are all of the prices of the stocks available freely online ? Or does it depend on the company ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear on what you're asking. Do you just want stock prices for different companies? If so [Yahoo finance](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/VTI/chart?p=VTI) has an interactive chart that lets you compare funds over different time periods. If you want to look at new companies that aren't publicly traded though I'm not sure how you would do that as that information is usually restricted to investors.

Comment: Ok that's exactly what I wanted to know. I reformulated my question

Comment: Okay, another thing to note if you end up using Yahoo finance is that their site isn't great for incorporating the effects of currency changes or dividend payments, so you only see the value of the dividends in the bottom of the chart, not incorporated into the final price and in terms of currency exchanges if you were buying US equities in Canadian dollars it won't show the effect of the relative differences in currencies. Websites like Sharesight.com are better for this, but they only let you track up to 10 funds, and they're not as good for comparing funds.